# Problems in DNS managed by Route 53

Tags: amazon-route53

Problem - Unable to resolve my sub-domain name through AWS route53,I have created a record on the route53 with the sub-domain name and IP address, but when I hit the IP it does not route the domain name I have created.

Answer (score 0):

If domain name is purchased from godaddy or some other provider then need to update Route 53 name server records in Domain name Dns record

Comment: Hi Abhishek,I am trying to create a record on R53 and route it one of my server IP.I have added one A type record on route 53.

Comment: Inside my main domain, I am creating a subdomain

Comment: you can add add A record for your subdomain under main domain

Comment: I did that but when trying to hit the IP the redirection is not happening

Comment: your main domian is redirecting to ip add?